# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: object and str, python

Tags: python, typeerror

I have this code:

```
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d')

class PrintMessage():

    def __init__(self,msg):
        self.msg = msg
        self.print_message()

        util = Utilities() #Class adds date to self.msg
        util.msg_with_time()

    def print_message(self): #print default msg
        print(self.msg)

class Utilities():
    def msg_with_time(msg):
       print(msg + ' on ' + today)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    inst = PrintMessage("My message")
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
 print(msg + ' on ' + today)
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Utilities' and 'str
```

I tried using int(today) in case it was that type of a mismatch, but still get the error. When i remove *"+ ' on ' + today"*, the msg prints, but without the date of course. Also, in the tutorial I'm following, it seems this exact code works. The tutorial uses python 3.1 while i'm using python 3.6, if it matters.

Edit: The default string prints, but the error gets thrown. Am using Eclipse workspace, btw.

I finally figured it out. The issue was, as i sortof had a hunch of, that i forgot to pass 'msg' to util.msg_with_time(), i.e so it becomes util.msg_with_time(msg).

Comment: The current code can't throw this error as you aren't passing anything to `util.msg_with_time`.

Comment: @ForceBru you are wrong, the OP is passing `self`, which is called `msg` in his/her case.

Comment: @EliKorvigo, yep, I'm wrong, indeed. This is what happens when you don't follow naming conventions: it becomes harder to understand the code...

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any point in making Utilities a class. Python is not Java.

Comment: @Daniel, i think the tutorial is trying to demonstrate python inheritance etc.

Comment: i wasn't able to delete the question

Answer (score 3):

In

```
class Utilities():
    def msg_with_time(msg):
        print(msg + ' on ' + today)
```

the argument you call `msg` is usually called `self`, because it is a reference to an instance of that class, making `msg_with_time` a bound instance method. And class `Utilities` defines no overload for `__add__` (the `+` operator), which is the source of your error: the interpreter doesn't know, how to add a `Utilities` instances and a `str` instances. I can't be sure, but it's likely that you want this:

```
class PrintMessage():

    def __init__(self,msg):
        self.msg = msg
        self.print_message()

        util = Utilities() #Class adds date to self.msg
        util.msg_with_time(self.msg)

    def print_message(self): #print default msg
        print(self.msg)

class Utilities():
    def msg_with_time(self, msg):
        print(msg + ' on ' + today)
```

In this case `Utilities` is actually pointless, because `msg_with_time` is a static method in all but definition (as it doesn't use the state encapsulated in `Utilities` instances). You can trivially replace it with a function

```
def msg_with_time(msg):
    print(msg + ' on ' + today)
```

Though you'll be far better off with a formatting template:

```
msg_with_time = '{{}} on {}'.format(today).format
```

Example:

```
msg_with_time('hello')  # hello on 18-01-14
```

Comment: You're right, i forgot to add 'self', before 'msg', right. Well i changed it to: def msg_with_time(self, msg): but still get the error. How do i 'overload' __add__ ?

Comment: @slackexchange you should define the `__add__` method in `Utilities`. Alternatively, if you are going to use formatting, you can define `__str__`. Anyway, in your particular situation, this is an overkill: the class is unnecessary. You really should define a function or use a formatting template.